# SQL row from table with equal probability

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `xyz` and there are 5 rows in it. And, I have a function which returns one row from `xyz` table sort by randomly to the user and then user adds a suggestions to it. so, the suggestions count increased.

Table `xyz` is like

```
 id       | suggestions 
----------+--------------
 276      |        0   
 111      |        0   
 222      |        0   
 333      |        0   
 444      |        0
```

simple function which currently I have is like this

```
 SELECT * FROM xyz
 ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

But my aim is to get at least 3 `suggestions` on all of the rows, and then any row can have any number of `suggestions`. so, if each time one row can be selected `randomly` with equal probability that will do the job. so, in the first 5 instance one row of the table will be selected and once all of them will be selected, then the process repeat again with equal probability of all the rows.

What I don't want is that - one row suggestions 4, but other row suggestions less than 3.

so, if function is called 15 times, I want it to be like this

```
id       | suggestions 
----------+--------------
 276      |        3   
 111      |        3   
 222      |        3   
 333      |        3   
 444      |        3 
 .....
```

but not like this

```
id       | suggestions 
----------+--------------
 276      |        1   
 111      |        0   
 222      |        5   
 333      |        6   
 444      |        3 
 .....
```

Comment: It's a good question to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just first order by `suggestions` then `random()`. This will select rows randomly where number of suggestions are less than other rows.

In below example select query is choosing rows randomly where suggestions is 2 since it's the smallest in the table.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table xyz (id int, suggestions int);
 INSERT into xyz VALUES ( 276    ,     2 );
 INSERT into xyz VALUES ( 111    ,     2 );
 INSERT into xyz VALUES ( 222    ,     3 );
 INSERT into xyz VALUES ( 333    ,     3 );
 INSERT into xyz VALUES ( 444    ,     3 );
```

First select query:

```
 SELECT *  FROM xyz
  ORDER BY SUGGESTIONS, RANDOM()
```

Output:

| id | suggestions |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2 |
| 276 | 2 |
| 222 | 3 |
| 444 | 3 |
| 333 | 3 |

Second select query:

```
 SELECT *  FROM xyz
  ORDER BY SUGGESTIONS, RANDOM()
```

Output:

| id | suggestions |
| --- | --- |
| 276 | 2 |
| 111 | 2 |
| 444 | 3 |
| 222 | 3 |
| 333 | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=19b728f911edd4c5edd15776b7ab1cc5)*

Comment: That's right, but it fails in one case. If 4 rows have 1 suggestions and 1 row has 0 suggestions. And if 10 different users call the function at the same time, then all users will get the same first row with 0 suggestions and then that first row will have 10 suggestions? isn't? 
Can we randomise with equal probability of each row?

Comment: Can we randomize with equal probability of each row?

Comment: That's true. Could you suggest any theory to overcome that? I can try to convert it to sql.

Comment: @Shas . . . Concurrent users are not part of the question that you asked.  This answers that question that you did ask.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with an emphasis on thread-safe code if that is what you want.  As a hint:  You can't do it only with a `select` query.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea as Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur, but I would use a DESCENDING ORDER BY.

I am using Oracle and create the following script on https://livesql.oracle.com. I use `floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10))` as RANDOM-Function and `WHERE rownum <= 1` within the UPDATE-Statement is the old Oracle syntax for `SELECT TOP` to get only the first data row.

```sql
drop table xyz;
create table xyz(id number, suggestions number);
insert into xyz(id, suggestions) values (276, 0);
insert into xyz(id, suggestions) values (111, 0);
insert into xyz(id, suggestions) values (222, 0);
insert into xyz(id, suggestions) values (333, 0);
insert into xyz(id, suggestions) values (444, 0);

update xyz set suggestions = suggestions + 1 
where id = (SELECT x.id FROM (SELECT xyz.id FROM xyz ORDER BY xyz.suggestions, floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) desc) x WHERE rownum <= 1);
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

| ID | SUGGESTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 276 | 0 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 222 | 0 |
| 333 | 0 |
| 444 | 0 |

```sql
update xyz set suggestions = suggestions + 1 
where id = (SELECT x.id FROM (SELECT xyz.id FROM xyz ORDER BY xyz.suggestions, floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) desc) x WHERE rownum <= 1);
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

| ID | SUGGESTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 276 | 0 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 222 | 0 |
| 333 | 1 |
| 444 | 0 |

```sql
update xyz set suggestions = suggestions + 1 
where id = (SELECT x.id FROM (SELECT xyz.id FROM xyz ORDER BY xyz.suggestions, floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) desc) x WHERE rownum <= 1);
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

| ID | SUGGESTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 276 | 0 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 222 | 1 |
| 333 | 1 |
| 444 | 0 |

```sql
update xyz set suggestions = suggestions + 1 
where id = (SELECT x.id FROM (SELECT xyz.id FROM xyz ORDER BY xyz.suggestions, floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) desc) x WHERE rownum <= 1);
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

| ID | SUGGESTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 276 | 1 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 222 | 1 |
| 333 | 1 |
| 444 | 0 |

```sql
update xyz set suggestions = suggestions + 1 
where id = (SELECT x.id FROM (SELECT xyz.id FROM xyz ORDER BY xyz.suggestions, floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) desc) x WHERE rownum <= 1);
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

| ID | SUGGESTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 276 | 1 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 222 | 1 |
| 333 | 1 |
| 444 | 1 |

```sql
update xyz set suggestions = suggestions + 1 
where id = (SELECT x.id FROM (SELECT xyz.id FROM xyz ORDER BY xyz.suggestions, floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) desc) x WHERE rownum <= 1);
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

| ID | SUGGESTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 276 | 1 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 222 | 1 |
| 333 | 2 |
| 444 | 1 |

```sql
update xyz set suggestions = suggestions + 1 
where id = (SELECT x.id FROM (SELECT xyz.id FROM xyz ORDER BY xyz.suggestions, floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) desc) x WHERE rownum <= 1);
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

| ID | SUGGESTIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 276 | 2 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 222 | 1 |
| 333 | 2 |
| 444 | 1 |